# tf_eigen build error

Tags: ros, catkin, buiding-errors

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm building my workspace with `catkin build` but I keep getting the following error

```
/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/mavros/mavros_extras/src/plugins/odom.cpp:20:33: fatal error: tf2_eigen/tf2_eigen.h: No such file or directory
#include <tf2_eigen/tf2_eigen.h>
```

tf2_eigen is in the list of packages which are done building:

```
Starting  >>> tf2_eigen                                                                                  
Finished  <<< roslaunch                                 [ 0.7 seconds ]                                  
Starting  >>> tf2_py                                                                                     
Finished  <<< tf2_eigen                                 [ 0.7 seconds ]
```

I have no idee what I did wrong because I didn't touched the `odom.cpp` file.

Thank you for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278129/tf_eigen-build-error/) by [MaximeRector](https://answers.ros.org/users/29590/maximerector/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2017-12-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved!

While looking at the `CMakeLists.txt` I saw tf2_eigen was not in the find_package list. I don't know if it needs to be there but adding it solved my problem.

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  mavros
  roscpp
  mavros_msgs
  sensor_msgs
  geometry_msgs
  std_msgs
  visualization_msgs
  urdf
  tf
  tf2_eigen
)
```

EDIT: Can't accept my own answer :(

---

Originally posted by [MaximeRector](https://answers.ros.org/users/29590/maximerector/) with karma: 60 on 2017-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-12-25**:
Accepted for you. Now you should have enough karma to do it next time.